# What is the difference between /ʌ/ and /ə/?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

In [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa#Indonesian_and_Malay) in the section talking about the use of schwa in Indonesian and Malay, they use /ʌ/ instead of /ə/ to write the words that have a stressed schwa.

Also the pronunciation by native speakers of some words in English, for instance ***done*** or ***must***, sound very similar to me as if they were pronounced like other vowels than /ʌ/.

/dʌn/ sounds similar to /don/

/mʌst/ sounds similar to /mʊst/

This make me thing that /ʌ/ is like /ə/ in the way that it is a reduced vowel, but the difference is that the former is used in stressed syllables. So how can I know the difference between the sounds of /ʌ/ and /ə/, if I want to pronounce both as a reduced vowel? Do I need to pay attention only to whether the syllable is stressed or whether it isn't to pronounce each sound?

The audio files for those words come with [this application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.study.english.pronunciation), but there are more than 2400 audio clips and I couldn't find the clips for ***done*** and ***must*** in the application's package, but I found the one for [***flourish***](https://www.anonfiles.cc/file/07b85a6eca20e837eccb0bd39278df06), that has the transcription /ˈflʌrɪʃ/ but it sounds to me like /ˈfləʊrɪʃ/

Comment: For *done* and *must*, I must say, the vowel is meant to be identical (barring nasalization). Compare [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/done#Pronunciation) and [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/must#Pronunciation). Which dialect is your reference here? Maybe they're different in something other than my own North American English.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I added a sample audio file.

Answer (score 2):

Those sounds are not always easy for learners to distinguish. But there are two differences to note.

First, they're articulated differently. [/ʌ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_unrounded_vowel) is low-mid / back / unrounded. [/ə/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_central_vowel) is mid / central / unrounded (in English). Hence, /ʌ/ is further back and slightly lower.

Second, many dialects of English use /ə/ only for [reduced vowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_reduction), which have interesting behaviour, such as dropping out or being replaced by [syllabic nasals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabic_consonant). Compare *sadden* /ˈsædən/ and *unkind* /ʌnˈkaɪnd/, where the vowels we're looking at are each in an unstressed syllable. It's possible for the /ə/ in *sadden* to drop in favour of a syllabic /n/, but the /ʌ/ in *unkind* can't drop.

However, a few dialects of English [make use of /ə/ in stressed syllables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_central_vowel#Occurrence), though that article says it's "often transcribed" as the very close /ɜ/. You could tune your ear by the pronunciation of *bud* in North American English vs. *bird* in Received Pronunciation. They're similar, but not identical.

Comment: I don't have troubles with the pronunciation of /ʌ/, but I'm curios about why some words that are transcribed with that vowel sound as some kind of reduced vowel other than /ʌ/ or /ə/. For instance I added the audio clip for ***flourish*** in the question that also has that peculiarity.